# Cannot find column when Sorting Gridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sorting, gridview

I need help sorting a gridview, below is my code:

```
Protected Sub TaskGridView_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Sorting

    'Retrieve the table from the session object.
    Dim dt As DataView = dsData.AsDataView


    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

        'Sort the data.
        If (GridView1.SortDirection() = SortDirection.Ascending) Then
            dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDirection.Descending
        Else
            dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDirection.Descending
        End If

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End If
```

I'm currently getting: 
Cannot find column [Whatever Column I'm sorting]

I'm new to VB and struggling to learn this and I can't make any of the other example code work.

Thank you for your help.

Added:
Other code:

ON page load I run my stored procedure and then it binds the data:

```
    Dim objConn As IDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim strBlder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim providerID As String = Request.QueryString("ProviderID")
    Dim providerName As String = Request.QueryString("ProviderName")
    GridView1.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast
```

Stored Procedure Query:

```
    GridView1.DataSource = dsData
    GridView1.AllowSorting = True
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

ASPX Code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-right: 0px" 
        AllowPaging = "True" PageSize = "50" AllowSorting = "true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status"></asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Set a breakpoint and inspect the values in the quick watch window.

Comment: I have and the table in DT has a column which matches the one I'm trying to sort.  It always crashes on this line:
dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDirection.Descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
If (GridView1.SortDirection() = SortDirection.Ascending) Then
    dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDirection.Descending
Else
    dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDirection.Descending
End If
```

With

```
If (GridView1.SortDirection() = SortDirection.Ascending) Then
    dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " ASC"
Else
    dt.Sort = e.SortExpression & " DESC"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you!  But why can't I compare the sortDirection to Ascending?  Do I need to compare it to a column or something?  If (GridView1.SortDirection() = SortDirection.Ascending)